# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel supports with dealing for xlsx

Tags: c#, ms-office, com-interop

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read an excel file and change some cells. It works perfectly with xls files.

I would like to know that, if I deploy the application to the client. They have to install the whole Microsoft Office application? as I think the only dll will not work, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that if you want to interact with traditional xls files then you can use http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/ which doesn't need Excel installed on the client. There are also several commercial solutions available like ExcelWriter.

Comment: this does not support excel 2007 at the moment.

Comment: Yes, hence the traditional xls files part :-) You might then be able to use Remy's suggestion if the file extension is xlsx

Comment: In summary, you could use the ExcelLibrary component for .xls and files and any of gdoron or Remy's answers for .xlsx files. You'd then remove your dependency on Excel.

Comment: I tried the ExcelLibrary but it would throw errors on the save using a stream every time. Had to scrap it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the clients must have Office installed.
I must add a warning, Interop is awkward you better use other (open source) libraries like  [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) or [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for .xlsx- 2007 excel sheets for automation.

***Update:***
Additional to the awkward of interop, It's **unsafe** when using in servers!!! see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757):

> "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."

Comment: it is not nice to ask them to install the office application on the server just for parsing excel files. dont you think?

Comment: @devn, I didn't understand what do you mean by install office on the server, but note my update when using Interop on servers.

Comment: The main problem with server side Excel automation is that when something goes wrong, you end up with lots of Excel instances in the background, usually with a dialog box waiting for someone to click it :-)

Comment: @dash, You are right, it's written there as well... Interop is a big headache.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are only .xslx files, you don't need Excel if you use the Open XML Api from Microsoft. It can read Excel files perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In case were Open XML and Excel interop is not an option, I would recommend Aspose. They have a nice suit of Office compatible components, including for Excel. And they are built for the server. We are using them since 5 years and it works pretty well.